# ERROR: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-windowmanager

I am a learner and am trying to display some set data in another layout which is solely created. I know this can be done through Intent but I have been trying to use Dialog according to tutorial video.

Here is the code below

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:ContactViewHolder, position:Int){
        holder.name.text = data[position].name
        holder.phoneNumber.text = data[position].phone
        holder.image.setImageResource(data[position].image)
        holder.card.setOnClickListener {

            Toast.makeText(context, data[position].phone, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val profilePage = Dialog(context)
            profilePage.setContentView(R.layout.profile)
            profilePage.window!!.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL)
            profilePage.setTitle("Profile page")

            val profileName = profilePage.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.profileName)
            val profileEmail = profilePage.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.profileEmail)
            val profileImage = profilePage.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.profileImage)

            profileName.text = data[position].name
            profileEmail.text = data[position].phone
            profileImage.setImageResource(data[position].image)

            profilePage.show()

        }



    }
```

I have also tried several options like setting permission in the manifest file but the error persist

Answer (score 0):

You need an `Activity` as a `Context` for `Dialog`s.

The `context` you passed to `Dialog` constructor likely isn't an activity.

Comment: Please how do i do that because i have tried Dialog(this@activityname), Dialog(activity) but futile

Comment: Where does the `context` you now have in your adapter come from? Change that.

Comment: The context is from the onCreateaviewHolder. Is there a better way to add click listener to make it displqy another layout with data from the adapter?